# AMQ212037: Connection failure in FROM Artemis 2.15.0

Tags: activemq-artemis, artemiscloud

Without any change, we received the following issue in one of the three nodes in the cluster. This node left the cluster after this issue and the clients could not connect to the cluster after this issue.

AMQ212037: Connection failure to /172.50.45.19:40266 has been detected: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]

```
2021-01-31 03:03:23,472 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to /172.50.45.19:40266 has been detected: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
2021-01-31 06:21:59,700 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ212037: Connection failure to /172.50.45.43:36714 has been detected: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer [code=GENERIC_EXCEPTION]
2021-01-31 08:31:53,887 WARNING [sun.rmi.transport.tcp] RMI TCP Accept-0: accept loop for ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=37258] throws: java.io.IOException: The server sockets created using the LocalRMIServerSocketFactory only accept connections from clients running on the host where the RMI remote objects have been exported.
at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(LocalRMIServerSocketFactory.java:114) [rt.jar:1.8.0_232]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:405) [rt.jar:1.8.0_232]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:377) [rt.jar:1.8.0_232]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_232]
```

Image used - `vromero/activemq-artemis:2.15.0`

Comment: Are you running all containers on the same machine? What client are you using? Can you share your connection url?

Comment: No, all pods are deployed on different nodes in k8s cluster

Answer (score 1):

This failure could be related to a docker/network issue. I would not use docker in a production environment, see [artemiscloud](https://github.com/artemiscloud) to run ActiveMQ Artemis on Kubernetes.
You can find the documentation at https://artemiscloud.io/

Comment: How is Artemis Cloud different from Artemis cluster in K8s ?

Comment: Any documentation I can go through?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the url website/doc https://artemiscloud.io/